# How to restart id counting on a table in PostgreSQL after deleting some previous data?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, database, postgresql

I'm using PostgreSQL database on Rails 2.3.8 and I need to restart auto increment ID on my table. How can I do that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do it directly in PostgreSQL using "alter sequence": http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-altersequence.html

Particularly "restart with"

I don't know how you would do it via the rails abstraction.

Answer (score 14):

If you truncate the table you can use the RESTART IDENTITY clause on the end.

Example:

`TRUNCATE TABLE foo RESTART IDENTITY;`

[TRUNCATE DOCUMENTATION](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/interactive/sql-truncate.html)

Comment: Please don't use URL shorteners. That prevents people from seeing where you link to. Jeff edited the link. [See here for more on the topic](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/99136/let-me-flag-that-for-you-url-shortener-cleanup/108295).

Comment: Thanks I was not aware shortened links were a nono.  Now I'm educated.

Answer (score 11):

You could do it in the following way:

`ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute("TRUNCATE TABLE your_table_name RESTART IDENTITY")`

Answer (score 5):

Try:

```
ActiveRecord::Base.connection.reset_pk_sequence!(table_name)
```

and check this answer for more details:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/7814519/1392282

Answer (score 3):

Check out [setval](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-sequence.html)

```
SELECT setval('foo', 42);           Next nextval will return 43
SELECT setval('foo', 42, true);     Same as above
SELECT setval('foo', 42, false);    Next nextval will return 42
```

Answer (score 3):

If you want to delete all data from table and want to reset id as well then try below code.

> ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute("TRUNCATE TABLE your_table_name
>   RESTART IDENTITY")

But if some relationship is present with table and you want to delete all data from table as well as related table data then try below code.

> ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute("TRUNCATE TABLE your_table_name
>   RESTART IDENTITY CASCADE")

Thanks and
please suggest if correction needed.

Answer (score 1):

You can use ActiveRecord in Rails.

You can easily do it from your rails console by running the following command:

```
Table_name.reset_primary_key
```

You can also use `SQL` :

```
TRUNCATE TABLE foo RESTART IDENTITY;
```

Comment: Examining the [documentation](https://apidock.com/rails/v6.0.0/ActiveRecord/AttributeMethods/PrimaryKey/ClassMethods/reset_primary_key), this only re-fetches or updates the primary key from the base class. It has nothing to do with the database.