# How to truncate n tables with one single ActiveRecord connection

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, sql-delete

I want to create a rake task in order to delete all records from a certain `n` number of tables and reset the values of the `id` column, so that when I create a new record it gets id 1. 
Previous question [Truncate table(s) with rails console](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13173618/truncate-tables-with-rails-console) is useful to get the job done for a single table (I would use `delete_all` in place of `destroy_all` if the task can be improved in performance):

```
Model.delete_all
ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute("TRUNCATE #{table_name} RESTART IDENTITY")
```

If I need to truncate more than one table, say tables `table1`, `table2`, `table3`, is there any chance to use a single ActiveRecord connection such as:

```
Model1.delete_all
Model2.delete_all
Model3.delete_all
ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute("TRUNCATE #{table1, table2, table3} RESTART IDENTITY")
```

and so avoid to establish multiple ActiveRecord connections like the example below?

```
Model1.delete_all
Model2.delete_all
Model3.delete_all
ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute("TRUNCATE #{table1} RESTART IDENTITY")
ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute("TRUNCATE #{table2} RESTART IDENTITY")
ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute("TRUNCATE #{table3} RESTART IDENTITY")
```

Comment: even if you try using raw SQL, it requires complex query, check this SO thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15926826/truncate-multi-tables

Comment: I might have found a solution in the Postgresql documentation: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/sql-truncate.html

Answer (score 1):

Rails 6.0 add new method: truncate_tables

```
ActiveRecord::Base.connection.truncate_tables(:table1_name, :table2_name)
```

truncate_tables has not yet provided api documentation, it is essentially based on the [truncate](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/DatabaseStatements.html#method-i-truncate) method

[source code](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/66cabeda2c46c582d19738e1318be8d59584cc5b/activerecord/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb#L179)

```
  def truncate(table_name, name = nil)
    execute(build_truncate_statements(table_name), name)
  end

  def truncate_tables(*table_names) # :nodoc:
    return if table_names.empty?

    with_multi_statements do
      disable_referential_integrity do
        Array(build_truncate_statements(*table_names)).each do |sql|
          execute_batch(sql, "Truncate Tables")
        end
      end
    end
  end
```

Rails 6.1 has made adjustments to prevent mistakenly deleting migrate-related tables [source code](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/914caca2d31bd753f47f9168f2a375921d9e91cc/activerecord/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb#L193)

```
  def truncate_tables(*table_names) # :nodoc:
    table_names -= [schema_migration.table_name, InternalMetadata.table_name]

    return if table_names.empty?

    with_multi_statements do
      disable_referential_integrity do
        statements = build_truncate_statements(table_names)
        execute_batch(statements, "Truncate Tables")
      end
    end
  end
```