# truncate and restart identity of a set of tables

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, rails-activerecord, truncation

My application uses `Postgresql`. 
I would need to remove all rows from a set of tables (`table1` to `table4`) and restart the `id` with one command from a rb file.

In the [Postgresql documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/sql-truncate.html) I found that TRUNCATE with RESTART IDENTITY would do the job as follows:

```
TRUNCATE table1, table2, table3, table4 RESTART IDENTITY;
```

According to [How to restart id counting on a table in PostgreSQL after deleting some previous data?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7606386/how-to-restart-id-counting-on-a-table-in-postgresql-after-deleting-some-previous) at Stackoverflow, I can use the following command:

```
ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute("TRUNCATE TABLE your_table_name RESTART IDENTITY")
```

So putting together the two documentations, would it be correct to use the following command:

```
ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute("TRUNCATE table1, table2, table3, table4 RESTART IDENTITY")
```

considering that in the [API dock](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Base/connection) documentation the `connection` method is reported as deprecated or moved?.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The recommended way nowadays is to use an [`ActiveRecord::Base.connection_pool.with_connection`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/ConnectionPool.html) block.

```
ActiveRecord::Base.connection_pool.with_connection do |conn|
  conn.execute("TRUNCATE table1, table2, table3, table4 RESTART IDENTITY")
end
```