# How do I require a file with a re-opened class?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, module, require

I'm quite new to RoR and I got a question regarding initialization of libraries.
how do I load up a class I extended from an existing class library in rails?

I'd like to extend the ActiveRecord::base as below based on [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2097052/rails-way-to-reset-seed-on-id-field)

```
# lib/active_record/add_reset_pk_sequence_to_base.rb
module ActiveRecord
  class Base
    def self.reset_pk_sequence
      case ActiveRecord::Base.connection.adapter_name
      when 'SQLite'
        new_max = maximum(primary_key) || 0
        update_seq_sql = "update sqlite_sequence set seq = #{new_max} where name = '#{table_name}';"
        ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute(update_seq_sql)
      when 'PostgreSQL'
        ActiveRecord::Base.connection.reset_pk_sequence!(table_name)
      else
        raise "Task not implemented for this DB adapter"
      end
    end     
  end
end
```

On purpose, I would like to use the extended class in seed.rb to reset auto increment of tables.
how do I load the file with the 'require' statement?
I have tried several ways, unfortunately, things didn't work out fine for me?

any advice would be very much appreciated?

Comment: I'm a little clueless on what you are trying to do, but your first steps could be to make a new file in config/initializers folder and require the file there

Comment: @JasdeepSingh thanks for your comment. anyway, after placing the file in the suggested folder, it worked like a charm!

Comment: Well I guess i can add that as an answer then.. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put the file in config/initializers folder or load it using require from that folder..

Comment: That doesn't seem like the right use of an initializer since its just monkey patching active record. I thought initializers were for setting the state of things such as configurations.