# Model.delete_all and make the ids start back at 1?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm using Model.delete_all in the Rails console to delete a table, but I noticed that the id numbers don't reset, they just start where it left off. How do I delete a table and make the ids start back at 1?

It's actually not a big deal, I'm just curious and think it'd be cleaner this way. Thank you!

Comment: similar question with answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2097052/rails-way-to-reset-seed-on-id-field

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Most databases have a concept of a sequence which auto increments as it's used.  ActiveRecord uses the underlying database sequence to create primary keys.  This gem (https://github.com/splendeo/activerecord-reset-pk-sequence) may help reset it for you depending on your database.

Answer (score 11):

To drop just one table (with the callbacks) and to get the IDs start from 1, there is no straight forward way in rails to do it.

You can do

1) `Model.destroy_all`

2) `ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute("TRUNCATE table_name")`

which will handle all that you want, for a single table, if that's what you need

Answer (score 8):

if you use postgresql you can execute this code

```
ActiveRecord::Base.connection.reset_pk_sequence!(Model.table_name)
```

after `Model.destroy_all`

Answer (score 6):

The best and easy way :

```
ActiveRecord::Base.connection.reset_pk_sequence!('table_name')
```

Ps : don't forget the 's' after the table_name

Answer (score 4):

If you only need to reset the ids:

```
ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute('ALTER TABLE table_name AUTO_INCREMENT = 1')
```

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the DB. In your app you shouldn't rely on the fact that IDs start with 1 and go sequentially, or even always increase for new records.
If you want a fresh DB, you can always do `rake db:drop`, then `rake db:create`.

Answer (score 0):

one liner

```
rake db:drop && rake db:create && rake db:migrate
```

back in business

Comment: didn't work for me I got an error running even the first part of that https://pastebin.com/raw/S3AgciCn

Comment: @barlop this answer is from a few years ago. perhaps the other answers can help you. also, make sure your server isn't running.